# Predicting speed of a car to pass checkpoints at correct times

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, optimization, numerical-methods

Let's say that I have a car that should pass checkpoints at predefined times. I can only control speed of the car - nothing else. The predefined passing times are unknown beforehand but the checkpoints expect smoothly changing speed of the car. So no wild unpredictable changes of the predefined passing times.

A checkpoint is passed every 0.1 to 3 seconds - i.e. there are 0.1 to 10 checkpoints per second. At each checkpoint I can compute the error. The error at the checkpoint is defined as the current elapsed time minus the elapsed time the car was supposed to pass the checkpoint.

Based on the error at the checkpoints I would like to modify the speed of the car so that at subsequent checkpoints the error diminishes.

In another words, I need to predict the speed of the car so that it matches the speed expected by the checkpoints. Unfortunately I cannot get the expected speed from the checkpoints directly. I can only get information how close to the expected passing time I got.

For now I predict the new speed as `u1 = u0 + error / constant` where the error is the `actual passing time - expected passing time`. It somehow works but the speed of the car oscillates quite heavily. Is there any algorithm that would do the job and remove the oscillations?

PS: The computations shall run real-time in web-browser and there is only one trial per checkpoint so that probably excludes implicit optimisation techniques.

Comment: This question is closely related to dynamical systems and control. You'll need to know some preliminaries before going further.

Comment: Thanks for hints. Will check it out ;)

Comment: Great, I implemented the discrete PID controller and it works perfectly ;) Thanks again for pointing me to the correct direction!

Comment: Glad to hear that!

Answer (score 0):

I implemented PID controller as defined here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PID_controller#Pseudocode

and it did the job!